# 'Options' object has no attribute 'module_name'

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Django 1.8a1 
 
Tastypie 0.12.0

I want to patch my object through api

When i try to curl api:

```
 
➜  sesame git:(migration) ✗ curl --dump-header -b cookies -v -H "X-CSRFToken: 5HA6yUXRtdf6KsHK6V52GKm1WkGWuvLh"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH --data '{"login": "111"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/serviceAccountEmail/50D2CB33-1ED8-4925-B542-9CE26C961C09/
```

I got error:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: cookies/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: cookies
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cookies
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#1)
> PATCH /api/v1/serviceAccountEmail/50D2CB33-1ED8-4925-B542-9CE26C961C09/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> Accept: */*
> X-CSRFToken: 5HA6yUXRtdf6KsHK6V52GKm1WkGWuvLh
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 16
> 
* upload completely sent off: 16 out of 16 bytes
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
 HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
 Date: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 21:56:48 GMT
 Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 Content-Type: application/json

{"error_message": "'Options' object has no attribute 'module_name'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/home/andrey/repos/sesame/tastypie/resources.py\", line 204, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/andrey/repos/sesame/tastypie/resources.py\", line 444, in dispatch_detail\n    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/andrey/repos/sesame/tastypie/resources.py\", line 467, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/andrey/repos/sesame/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1626, in patch_detail\n    self.update_in_place(request, bundle, deserialized)\n\n  File \"/home/andrey/repos/sesame/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1649, in update_in_place\n    return self.obj_update(bundle=original_bundle, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/andrey/repos/sesame/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2167, in obj_update\n    return self.save(bundle, skip_errors=skip_errors)\n\n  File \"/home/andrey/repos/sesame/tastypie/resou* Closing connection 1
rces.py\", line 2245, in save\n    self.authorized_update_detail(self.get_object_list(bundle.request), bundle)\n\n  File \"/home/andrey/repos/sesame/tastypie/resources.py\", line 650, in authorized_update_detail\n    auth_result = self._meta.authorization.update_detail(object_list, bundle)\n\n  File \"/home/andrey/repos/sesame/tastypie/authorization.py\", line 214, in update_detail\n    permission = '%s.change_%s' % (klass._meta.app_label, klass._meta.module_name)\n\nAttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'module_name'\n"}%
```

Google can't help me with this situation

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your `curl` option:

As per the [docs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
-b, --cookie <name=data>
```

> (HTTP) Pass the data to the HTTP server as a cookie. It is supposedly
>   the data previously received from the server in a "Set-Cookie:" line.
>   The data should be in the format "NAME1=VALUE1; NAME2=VALUE2".
>
> If no '=' symbol is used in the line, it is treated as a filename to
>   use to read previously stored cookie lines from, which should be used
>   in this session if they match. Using this method also activates the
>   "cookie parser" which will make curl record incoming cookies too,
>   which may be handy if you're using this in combination with the -L,
>   --location option. The file format of the file to read cookies from should be plain HTTP headers or the Netscape/Mozilla cookie file
>   format.
>
> The file specified with -b, --cookie is only used as input. No cookies
>   will be written to the file. To store cookies, use the -c,
>   --cookie-jar option.
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.